# Create new CsQuery object without inheritance

Tags: jquery, csquery

directly to the question:

I have CsQuery object with some data.

```
 CQ html=new CQ("<div id='wrapper'> <p id='getIt'></p> </div>");
```

I want to get p and assign it to a new CQ object :

```
 Cq newHtml=html["p"];
```

***When I do that, it also inherits the  original DIV. How can I make p element be the 'root'. ?***

I have been trying everything:

after **html.MakeRoot()** if I use .Select() it still returns the DIV.

Also I tried using the  **.Find** function (it search within the selected element) but it doesn't resolve my problem because I use a third-party library function which uses **.Select()**...

I know that I can do something like that

```
    CQ html=new CQ(html["p"].RenderSelection());
```

But it's kind of....

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I humbly suggest the [new 1.3 creation syntax](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery/blob/master/documentation/create.md) over the old one:

```
CQ html=CQ.CreateFragment("<div id='wrapper'> <p id='getIt'></p> </div>");
```

Now, like you wanted, we want to get the inner p element, then create a new DOM context, we can do this by invoking the constructing method again. I think code will be easier :)

```
 CQ html = CQ.CreateFragment("<div id='wrapper'> <p id='getIt'>Hello</p> </div>");
 //Create a _new_ context
 CQ newHtml=CQ.CreateFragment(html["p"]);
 newHtml.Text("World");
 Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",html["p"].Text(),newHtml.Text());//Hello World
 Console.Read();
```

If you have any more questions, feel free to let me know.

Comment: For fragments, I like the implicit method: `CQ html = "... html .. "` :)